# trigger a function only once per user

Tags: django

I have an application where each user who has previously authenticated can access the index.html page with a button to trigger a time.sleep(t) function.
What I would like is that the same user cannot retrigger the function.

**urls.py**

```
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
urlpatterns = [
    path('page1',  login_required(function=views.page1, login_url="login"), name="page1"),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def page1(request):
    if(request.GET.get("arg")=="nap" and request.session.get("nap") == None):
            request.session["nap"] = True
            sleep(1, 5)
            request.session["nap"] = None
    return render(request, 'page1.html')

def sleep(t, n):
    for i in range(0,n):
        time.sleep(t)
        print(f"nap n°{i}")
```

**index.html**

```
<button type="button">
    <a href="{% url 'page1' %}?arg=nap"> NAP </a>
</button>
```

[image]

Comment: your code and our output screenshot don't match.

Comment: Hello, I just changed the number of iterations and the name *sleep* by *nap*